# why java version not updated on mac machine?

Tags: java, macos

I  checked my java version from terminal .I got this information

```
Last login: Sun Mar 15 08:46:08 on ttys000
localhost:~ naveenkumar$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
localhost:~ naveenkumar$
```

I install new java 1.8 JRE .close my terminal .Agan i type java -version .I found the same version .

why ? how to upgrade java version.

Comment: You're going to have to point your path to the updated version.

Comment: configure your Java path in order to make it updated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils how to update the path .could you please give steps

Comment: @taimeili123 please provide the steps to update java path

Comment: @PallaviSharma check out the answer i posted. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You installed Java 8 but it didn't overwrite this:  `/usr/bin/java`

The easiest way for you to solve this problem is to install Java 8 JDK, not JRE. After install JDK, your path should be automatically updated.